# Can React DnD be used for implementing resizing

Tags: reactjs, resize, react-dnd

is it possible to use React DnD to implement resizing in general?

I'm looking at resizing table columns in a React app.

I have not been able to locate any examples of resizing in React DnD docs as of yet..

Comment: I am also looking for this. Did you found a solution?

Comment: does anyone able to get solution for this ? How to implement resize in an App which have React DND already ?